# `Type cannot be null` exception when trying to run out Stored Procedure using Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to invoke a Stored Procedure whose signature looks like the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE FIND_FIRST_BOOKMARK_GT(bookmark IN NUMBER, cur OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
```

I am using Spring-Data JPA and have tried a number of different variants, but all of them follow more or less the following pattern. My entity model is decorated as follows:

```
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "Response.findFirstBookmarkGreaterThan", procedureName = "FIND_FIRST_BOOKMARK_GT",
    resultClasses = Response.class,
    parameters = {
        @StoredProcedureParameter(name = "bookmark", mode = ParameterMode.IN, type = Long.class),
        @StoredProcedureParameter(name = "cur", mode = ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR, type = void.class)
    })
})
```

Then I have my repository which looks like the following:

```
@Repository
public interface ResponseRepository extends CrudRepository<Response, Long>{
    @Procedure("Response.findFirstBookmarkGreaterThan")
    Response findFirstBookmarkGreaterThan(@Param("bookmark") Long bookmark);
}
```

I have followed the instructions from quite a few examples, but I am always left with the same error, namely:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Type cannot be null
at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.AbstractParameterRegistrationImpl.setHibernateType(AbstractParameterRegistrationImpl.java:182) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.AbstractParameterRegistrationImpl.<init>(AbstractParameterRegistrationImpl.java:131) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.AbstractParameterRegistrationImpl.<init>(AbstractParameterRegistrationImpl.java:140) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.AbstractParameterRegistrationImpl.<init>(AbstractParameterRegistrationImpl.java:97) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.NamedParameterRegistration.<init>(NamedParameterRegistration.java:41) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl.registerParameter(ProcedureCallImpl.java:344) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.StoredProcedureQueryImpl.registerStoredProcedureParameter(StoredProcedureQueryImpl.java:152) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.StoredProcedureJpaQuery.newAdhocStoredProcedureQuery(StoredProcedureJpaQuery.java:175) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.StoredProcedureJpaQuery.createStoredProcedure(StoredProcedureJpaQuery.java:130) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.StoredProcedureJpaQuery.doCreateQuery(StoredProcedureJpaQuery.java:89) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.StoredProcedureJpaQuery.createQuery(StoredProcedureJpaQuery.java:80) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
......
```

Any ideas what is wrong here?

Comment: Can you try the code without the cur parameter reference declaration and check if the error still exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to get this syntax working as such, however, the notion of retrieving from a stored procedure is effectively a shorthand for selecting from (possibly a view) mixed with applying some input based function. To that effect, I have replaced my stored procedure with a function / table that yields the same effect.

```
@Query("SELECT r FROM RESPONSES r WHERE BOOKMARK = FIND_FIRST_BOOKMARK_GT(:bookmark)")
Response findFirstBookmarkGreaterThan(@Param("bookmark") Long bookmark);
```

This uses the `@Query` syntax in conjunction with a table and a function, whose overall logic is identical to calling the stored procedure I had intended. Although a little more difficult to follow perhaps, the syntax is at least much shorter than using the `@NamedStoredProcedureQuery`.

The function does the same thing the stored procedure originally did EXCEPT for the last part which was a `SELECT INTO`, this is now encapsulated as part of the `@Query`.

Answer (score 2):

Using native Query we can also call store procedure.
If you are using MySQL then following will be the systex:

```
 @Query(nativeQuery = true,value = "call getEmployeeList")
 List<Employee> getEmployeeList();
```

Comment: What is the stored procedure has arguments?

Answer (score 1):

Faced with the same issue using  `@Procedure`. As a workaround, you could refer to the entityManager in the service class and call procedure from it.

```
@Service
public interface ResponseService {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;

    public Response findFirstBookmarkGreaterThan(Long bookmark){
          Query query  = entityManager.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("Response.findFirstBookmarkGreaterThan");
          query.setParameter("bookmark", bookmark);
          return query.getFirstResult();
    };
}
```

Note that Response must be an `@Entity`.

Comment: This doesnt work! This must be a class not an interface.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I faced with same issue and get fixed finally after a couple of hours of "read docs-try-error". Maybe this could be useful to someone. Your repository must look like this:

```
@Repository
public interface ResponseRepository extends CrudRepository<Response, Long>{
    @Procedure(name = "Response.findFirstBookmarkGreaterThan")
    Response findFirstBookmarkGreaterThan(@Param("bookmark") Long bookmark);
}
```

The key is at @Procedure annotation. Use "name" instead of "value" (by default) when coding this annotation.
This article at Baeldung blog gave me the final pull to resolve this error: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-stored-procedures.

Comment: If you are saying the Response class should be an entity, the response class of my procedure is not an entity(not a table in the database). How can this be handled?